# How to statically link to TBB?

Tags: c++, linker, tbb

How can I statically link the [intel's TBB libraries](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/) to my application?
I know [all the caveats](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/wiki/index.php?title=Using_TBB) such as unfair load distribution of the scheduler, but I don't need the scheduler, just the containers, so it's ok.

Anyways I know this can be done, although its undocumented, however I just can't seem to find the way to do it right now (although I've seen it before somewhere).

So does anyone know or have any clues?

thanks

Comment: any platform really, both windows, Linux, plus solaris. I need to know what extra defines to add for proper compilation.

Answer (score 11):

This is strongly not recommended:

> Is there a version of TBB that provides statically linked libraries?
>
> TBB is not provided as a statically linked library, for the following reasons*:
>
> Most libraries operate locally. For example, an Intel(R) MKL FFT transforms an array. It is irrelevant how many copies of the FFT there are. Multiple copies and versions can coexist without difficulty. But some libraries control program-wide resources, such as memory and processors. For example, garbage collectors control memory allocation across a program. Analogously, TBB controls scheduling of tasks across a program. To do their job effectively, each of these must be a singleton; that is, have a sole instance that can coordinate activities across the entire program. Allowing k instances of the TBB scheduler in a single program would cause there to be k times as many software threads as hardware threads. The program would operate inefficiently, because the machine would be oversubscribed by a factor of k, causing more context switching, cache contention, and memory consumption. Furthermore, TBB's efficient support for nested parallelism would be negated when nested parallelism arose from nested invocations of distinct schedulers.
>
> The most practical solution for creating a program-wide singleton is a dynamic shared library that contains the singleton. Of course if the schedulers could cooperate, we would not need a singleton. But that cooperation requires a centralized agent to communicate through; that is, a singleton!
>
> Our decision to omit a statically linkable version of TBB was strongly influenced by our OpenMP experience. Like TBB, OpenMP also tries to schedule across a program. A static version of the OpenMP run-time was once provided, and it has been a constant source of problems arising from duplicate schedulers. We think it best not to repeat that history. As an indirect proof of the validity of these considerations, we could point to the fact that Microsoft Visual C++ only provides OpenMP support via dynamic libraries.

Source: http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/faq/11#sthash.t3BrizFQ.dpuf

Comment: Does this mean that by using a shared library TBB has data that is shared across multiple processes on the same machine?  That is, a "program" (where it says "program-wide singleton") means multiple processes?  Or does it mean that if you statically link TBB that you will get multiple singletons in a single process?  I don't understand how it would work in the second case.

Comment: Intel provides build/big_iron.inc specifically for the purpose of building a static library. So, I don't think this answer paints the full picture. Suggest sourcedelica's answer below as the correct one.

Comment: Thanks but the question was not "is it recommended to build TBB statically"

Answer (score 8):

**EDIT** - Changed to use `extra_inc`.  Thanks Jeff!

Build with the following parameter:

```
make extra_inc=big_iron.inc
```

The static libraries will be built.  See the caveats in `build/big_iron.inc`.

Answer (score 5):

## Build static libraries from source

After acquiring the source code from https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/, build TBB like this:

`make extra_inc=big_iron.inc`

If you need extra options, then instead build like this:

`make extra_inc=big_iron.inc <extra options>`

## Running multiple TBB programs per node

If you run a multiprocessing application, e.g. using MPI, you may need to explicitly initialize the TBB scheduler with the appropriate number of threads to avoid oversubscription.

An example of this in a large application can be found in https://github.com/m-a-d-n-e-s-s/madness/blob/master/src/madness/world/thread.cc.

## Comment on documentation

This feature has been available for many years (since at least 2013), although it is not documented for the reasons described in other answers.

## Historical note

This feature was originally developed because IBM Blue Gene and Cray supercomputers either did not support shared libraries or did not perform well when using them, due to the lack of a locally mounted filesystem.

Answer (score 3):

Using the opensource version:

After running "make tbb"，go to the build/linux_xxxxxxxx_release folder.

Then run:

```
ar -r libtbb.a concurrent_hash_map.o concurrent_queue.o concurrent_vector.o 
dynamic_link.o itt_notify.o cache_aligned_allocator.o pipeline.o queuing_mutex.o 
queuing_rw_mutex.o reader_writer_lock.o spin_rw_mutex.o spin_mutex.o critical_section.o
task.o tbb_misc.o tbb_misc_ex.o mutex.o recursive_mutex.o condition_variable.o 
tbb_thread.o concurrent_monitor.o semaphore.o private_server.o rml_tbb.o 
task_group_context.o governor.o market.o arena.o scheduler.o observer_proxy.o 
tbb_statistics.o tbb_main.o concurrent_vector_v2.o concurrent_queue_v2.o 
spin_rw_mutex_v2.o task_v2.o
```

And you should get libtbb.a as output.

Note that your program should build both with "-ldl" and libtbb.a

Answer (score 3):

Although not officially endorsed by the TBB team, it is possible to build your own statically linked version of TBB with `make extra_inc=big_iron.inc`.

I have not tested it on Windows or MacOS, but on Linux, it worked ([source](https://github.com/philipp-classen/tbb-static-linking-tutorial/blob/master/Dockerfile#L13)):

```
wget https://github.com/01org/tbb/archive/2017_U6.tar.gz
tar xzfv 2017_U6.tar.gz
cd tbb-2017_U6
make extra_inc=big_iron.inc
```

The generated files are in `tbb-2017_U6/build/linux*release`.

When you link your application to the static TBB version:

- Call g++ with the `-static` switch
- Link against tbb (`-ltbb`) and pthread (`-lpthread`)

In my test, I also needed to explicitely reference all `.o` files from the manually build TBB version. Depending on your project, you might also need to pass `-pthread` to gcc.

I have created a toy example to document all the steps in this Github repository:

- [tbb-static-linking-tutorial](https://github.com/philipp-classen/tbb-static-linking-tutorial)

It also contains test code to make sure that the generated binary is portable on other Linux distributions.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it does not appear to be possible: [From TBB site.](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/wiki/index.php?title=Using_TBB#Is_there_a_version_of_TBB_that_provides_statically_linked_libraries.3F).
One suggestion on the Intel forum was to compile it manually if you really need the static linkage: [From Intel Forum](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-threading-building-blocks/topic/64241/).

Comment: It's possible.  They just refuse to document it because they don't want anyone to do it.

Answer (score -1):

Just link the files, I just did it and works. Here's the SConscript file. There's two minor things, a symbol which has the same name in tbb and tbbmalloc which I had to prevent to be multiply defined, and I prevented the usage of ITT_NOTIFY since it creates another symbol with the same name in both libs.

```
Import('g_CONFIGURATION')
import os
import SCutils
import utils

tbb_basedir = os.path.join(
    g_CONFIGURATION['basedir'],
    '3rd-party/tbb40_233oss/')

#print 'TBB base:', tbb_basedir
#print 'CWD: ', os.getcwd()

ccflags = []
cxxflags = [
    '-m64',
    '-march=native',
    '-I{0}'.format(tbb_basedir),
    '-I{0}'.format(os.path.join(tbb_basedir, 'src')),
    #'-I{0}'.format(os.path.join(tbb_basedir, 'src/tbb')),
    '-I{0}'.format(os.path.join(tbb_basedir, 'src/rml/include')),
    '-I{0}'.format(os.path.join(tbb_basedir, 'include')),
]
cppdefines = [
#    'DO_ITT_NOTIFY',
    'USE_PTHREAD',
    '__TBB_BUILD=1',
]
linkflags = []

if g_CONFIGURATION['build'] == 'debug':
    ccflags.extend([
        '-O0',
        '-g',
        '-ggdb2',
    ])
    cppdefines.extend([
        'TBB_USE_DEBUG',
    ])

else:
    ccflags.extend([
        '-O2',
    ])


tbbenv = Environment(
    platform = 'posix',
    CCFLAGS=ccflags,
    CXXFLAGS=cxxflags,
    CPPDEFINES=cppdefines,
    LINKFLAGS=linkflags
)

############################################################################
# Build verbosity
if not SCutils.has_option('verbose'):
    SCutils.setup_quiet_build(tbbenv, True if SCutils.has_option('colorblind') else False)
############################################################################



tbbmallocenv = tbbenv.Clone()

tbbmallocenv.Append(CCFLAGS=[
    '-fno-rtti',
    '-fno-exceptions',
    '-fno-schedule-insns2',
])

#tbbenv.Command('version_string.tmp', None, '')

# Write version_string.tmp
with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'version_string.tmp'), 'wb') as fd:
    (out, err, ret) = utils.xcall([
        '/bin/bash',
        os.path.join(g_CONFIGURATION['basedir'], '3rd-party/tbb40_233oss/build/version_info_linux.sh')
    ])

    if ret:
        raise SCons.Errors.StopError('version_info_linux.sh execution failed')

    fd.write(out);
    #print 'put version_string in', os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'version_string.tmp')
    #print out
    fd.close()

result = []

def setup_tbb():
    print 'CWD: ', os.getcwd()
    tbb_sources = SCutils.find_files(os.path.join(tbb_basedir,'src/tbb'), r'^.*\.cpp$')
    tbb_sources.extend([
        'src/tbbmalloc/frontend.cpp',
        'src/tbbmalloc/backref.cpp',
        'src/tbbmalloc/tbbmalloc.cpp',
        'src/tbbmalloc/large_objects.cpp',
        'src/tbbmalloc/backend.cpp',
        'src/rml/client/rml_tbb.cpp',
    ])


    print tbb_sources
    result.append(tbbenv.StaticLibrary(target='libtbb', source=tbb_sources))


setup_tbb()

Return('result')
```