# OpenCv static compilation on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, opencv, static-linking

I have static libraries of Opencv on my computer and I can link against them so my app does not need those libraries any more. I still need ffmpeg and other dependencies on a new computer though. I know I will need the static version of all the libraries. But some of them like tbb or gstreamer are not easy to find. Any better way?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read this post. Static linking of tbb is not recommended by Intel.
[How to statically link to TBB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638278/how-to-statically-link-to-tbb)