# Relative RPATHs when building conan / cmake project on MacOS

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries, macos-high-sierra, conan

I have a simple C++ project with a dependency on Intel TBB (which requires the use of shared libraries). I'm trying to build this using the Conan package manager combined with CMake, and I've already been able to use this setup to add non-shared dependencies with no problems.

---

My first attempt (combining the information from [conan's conanfile.txt documentation for using packages](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/using_packages/conanfile_txt.html#imports) and [conan's conanfile.py reference guide](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile/methods.html#imports)) used a `conanfile.py` like this:

```python
import os
from conans import ConanFile, CMake

class MyProjectConan(ConanFile):
    settings = 'os', 'compiler', 'build_type', 'arch'
    requires = 'TBB/2018_U6@conan/stable'
    generators = 'cmake'

    def build(self):
        cmake = CMake(self)
        cmake.configure()
        cmake.build()

    def imports(self):
        self.copy('*.dll', src='bin', dst='bin')
        self.copy('*.dylib*', src='lib', dst='bin')
        self.copy('*.so', src='lib', dst='bin')
```

and a `CMakeLists.txt` like this:

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
project(MyProject)

add_definitions("-std=c++17")

include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
conan_basic_setup()

add_executable(main src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main ${CONAN_LIBS})
```

(my `src/main.cpp` is just a direct copy of [the test file for the TBB package](https://github.com/conan-community/conan-tbb/blob/stable/2018_U6/test_package/main.cpp))

This built just fine;

```sh
conan install -if build .
conan build -bf build .
```

But running `./build/bin/main` failed with this error:

> ```
> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libtbb.dylib
>   Referenced from: <project-dir>/./build/bin/main
>   Reason: image not found
> Abort trap: 6
> ```

I'm on MacOS, and this error is similar to a [known (but apparently fixed) issue](https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/1238), so I tried running the binary from its own directory; `cd build/bin; ./main`, but saw the same error. I'm not sure why this didn't work, but I moved on to another approach without spending much time debugging it.

---

Next I followed the [conan documentation's "different approaches" for RPATHs guide](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/howtos/manage_shared_libraries/rpaths.html#different-approaches) to end up with this:

```python
class MyProjectConan(ConanFile):
    # (rest of class is same as before)

    def imports(self):
        self.copy('*.dll', src='bin', dst='bin')
        self.copy('*.dylib*', src='lib', dst='lib') # changed bin to lib
        self.copy('*.so', src='lib', dst='lib') # changed bin to lib
```

and this:

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
project(MyProject)

add_definitions("-std=c++17")

include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
conan_basic_setup(KEEP_RPATHS)

if(APPLE)
    set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "@executable_path/../lib")
else()
    set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "$ORIGIN/../lib")
endif()

add_executable(main src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main ${CONAN_LIBS})
```

Which builds and even runs! But when I inspect the executable I see that it references `/Users/me/.conan/data/TBB/2018_U6/conan/stable/package/03db91a62823ebc2b1df6e5cf549c2f674116656/lib`, which is obviously not what that code is supposed to do (I was expecting to see `@rpath/../lib` or similar). I have also verified that the binary is indeed using this path, and not the files placed in its sibling `lib` folder.

---

At this point I'm stuck. I can see that CMake has [a few options for RPATH handling](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/cmake/RPATH-handling), but nothing there looks particularly relevant, and I don't understand why the code in my second attempt (taken directly from conan's documentation) doesn't work.

What do I need to do to get a shared library working with conan? (ideally cross-platform, but at least on MacOS)

Comment: Hi @Dave. Have you tried to directly set DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH before running the executables? Since OSX introduce the protection system, it is not possible to run anything that needs paths to shared libs without directly setting ``DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH  /path/to/executable``. Using generators like ``virtualrunenv`` and providing it in command line might help. Have you had a look to: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/howtos/manage_shared_libraries/env_vars.html#using-virtualrunenv-generator? Also, it is sometimes better to use github issues in https://github.com/conan-io/conan, even for questions.

Comment: @drodri yes, for the first attempt if I set `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=./build/bin` when running the executable, it runs, which I guess solves the first mystery. But I'm looking to build an executable which just-works™️ so that isn't a great solution for me. It seems RPATHs avoid this requirement (after all, the problem in my second case isn't that it fails to find the library, but that it is using an absolute path to my `.conan` cache, instead of a relative path to the copied files); do you have any idea why it ignored my `CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH` in the second attempt?

Comment: Here's how to build TBB as a static library: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38858420/158658

Comment: @sourcedelica note that TBB **strongly discourages** doing that (https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/faq/11)

Comment: Might be but we have hundreds of applications that use it that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out the problem in the second attempt after looking through CMake's [other variables](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-variables.7.html) one-by-one.

The missing setting is this:

```
set(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH ON)
```

Hopefully this can be added to the Conan documentation, because with it enabled everything works exactly like it should. For final reference, my build files are:

#### conanfile.py

```py
from conans import ConanFile, CMake

class MyProjectConan(ConanFile):
    settings = ('os', 'compiler', 'build_type', 'arch')
    requires = (
        'TBB/2018_U6@conan/stable',
    )
    generators = 'cmake'

    def build(self):
        cmake = CMake(self)
        cmake.configure()
        cmake.build()

    def imports(self):
        self.copy('*.dll', src='bin', dst='bin')
        self.copy('*.dylib*', src='lib', dst='lib')
        self.copy('*.so', src='lib', dst='lib')
```

#### CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
project(MyProject)

add_definitions("-std=c++11") # to use 17, must also set '-s cppstd=17' on conan install

include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
conan_basic_setup(KEEP_RPATHS)

if(APPLE)
    set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "@executable_path/../lib")
else()
    set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "$ORIGIN/../lib")
endif()
set(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH ON) # <-- this is the line which is missing in the Conan documentation!

add_executable(main src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main ${CONAN_LIBS})
```

#### Build with

```sh
conan install -if build .
conan build -bf build .
```

#### Run with

```sh
./build/bin/main
```

And it will all just work, as long as the generated bin and lib directories remain siblings. The output binary contains only relative paths; no machine-specific paths.

Comment: this is probably a bad idea if you want you package conan to be installed on machines other than yours because the rpath will point to your home dir that may not exists on other machines

Comment: @OznOg it's been a while since I was looking at it but the issue you mention is exactly what I was trying to fix, and IIRC the solution I posted here does indeed fix it. Inspecting the output binary should show that it is using _relative_ rpaths, not absolute.

Comment: I think I did not understood your question on the first hand :), give up my comment.